# Pandas: checking invalid values in to_datetime function

Tags: pandas, datetime, to-date, coerce

im trying to convert string into datetype using:

```
df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

that throws: ('month must be in 1..12', 'occurred at index 'my_column')

Adding errors='coerce' fixes problem

```
df.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
```

But is there any way to check and display the invalid values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a new column then use boolean indexing:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'str':['2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-13-01']})
# adding a new column that is datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['str'], errors='coerce')
# boolean indexing
df[df['date'].isna()]


        str     date
2   2019-13-01   NaT
```

Comment: And what about checking when both values are null? I've tried:     *df[df['date','date1']].where(df['date'].notnull() & df['date1'].isna())* where date is the original value and date1 is the new column changed to datetime. I get nulls everywhere.

Comment: to find if both values are null: `df[df['date'].isna() & df['date1'].isna()]`